# Safe Unsubscribe with @try / @catch in Swift XCode 8.2.1

Tags: swift, exception, swift3

In the [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) article how to convert this **Safe Unsubscribe with @try / @catch** part in Swift 3?
How to have a pure @try with empty @catch in swift3 for special purposes

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, `catch` blocks are optional. In fact, one can avoid the `do`/`catch` blocks entirely by using the optional `try` syntax. Take for example a `JSONSerialization` `try`/`catch` solution. If one does not wish to handle caught errors in any way, it can simply be done like this:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/")!)
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [], options: .prettyPrinted)
```

Alternatively, if one wishes to catch any potential errors, the syntax would be as follows:

```
do {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/")!)
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: [], options: .prettyPrinted)
} catch let error {
    //do something with error
}
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: What?.. I use these in my own project. If they don't work then please show how you are implementing them. @Husyn

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to catch the NSException directly in Swift. This part has to be Objective-C code.

```
@try {
    [self removeObserver:observer forKeyPath:keyPath];
} @catch (NSException * __unused exception) {
    // nothing to do
}
```

I implemented a simple category on NSObject that provides a `safelyRemoveObserver:forKeyPath:` method that can be used  from within your Swift code: https://gist.github.com/samuel-mellert/2bb38ba4887aeecac462ad972e25d26f